# Adding elements to list in Nextjs from a json response

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently working on a **Nextjs** project, where I have to get a response from an **API** and convert it into a **JSON response**.

Let's say this is an API, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

I fetch data from this API using getStaticProps,

```js
var fetch_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(fetch_url);
  const data = await res.json();

  return {
    props: { worksheets_data: data },
  };
};
```

I want only unique usernames from the JSON response and display them on my webpage.

Help me with this! Thanks in advance!

Comment: The data you get is already an array after you use ```res.json```. Why do you want to store it in another array ```userName``` ?

Comment: Actually, this is not the same API, I work with. The Original API, I work with has multiple users with the same name, so I want to create a list where there are no duplicate names, in other words, my array should contain only unique elements. So, I thought of creating an array where there will be no duplicate elements

Comment: Then, your question is how to filter an array of objects with a unique key. you can use ```array.filter()``` to make this happen.

Comment: Ohh ok, will change my question,

Comment: would suggest you to give a sample input (with duplicate values) and what is your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple code for displaying data as you needed.
(Although I checked the backend result and usernames are already Unique)

```
import React from "react";

const Index = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      {props.worksheets_data &&
        props.worksheets_data.map((el) => <div key={el.id}>{el.username}</div>)}
    </>
  );
};

const fetch_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(fetch_url);
  const data = await res.json();

  const filteredData = data.filter(
    (obj, idx, arr) => idx === arr.findIndex((o) => obj.name === o.name)
  );

  return {
    props: { worksheets_data: filteredData },
  };
};

export default Index;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and `findIndex` to get the unique data.

```js
var fetch_url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

export const getStaticProps = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(fetch_url);
  const data = await res.json();

  const filtered = data.filter(
    (obj, i, arr) => i === arr.findIndex(o => obj.name === o.name)
  );

  return {
    props: { worksheets_data: filtered },
  };
};
```